# how to use Input stream reader to load files from internal memory android

Tags: android, inputstream

my app requires that texts be saved(user choice) into the internal memory and then i want something like a favorite feature where user clicks on a button and a favorite activity starts to load the files saved in the memory(internal). in my program there are multiple texts and i have used a random generator to save the files as "fav1" "fav2" etc.. where the integer part is generated randomly. the problem is that now i don't know how to give my file name so that the files are retrieved and shown in a text View.

```
public void load(String name){


    try {
```

**BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(filename)));**

```
        String inputString;

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                

        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {

            stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");

        }

        show.setText(stringBuffer.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

so how do you suggest i retrieve the files, its getting frustrating anyone help.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it easily by the following code;
as you said it reads from file from internal storage.

```
private String readFromFile(String fname) {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fname+".txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            show.setText(stringBuilder.toString());                

            inputStream.close();

        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
to read from the path contains path seperators

```
File myFile = new File(fname+".txt"); // path contains full path to the file including file name
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            show.setText(stringBuilder.toString());    
            myReader.close();
```

**EDIT 2**

to list files from specific directory and to choose the required file by its name.

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sample");

 // check the existance of the parent directory
 if (directory.exists()) { 

 // get the list of files from the directory and keep it in an array of type File.
                    File[] fileList = directory.listFiles(); 

                for (File file : fileList) {

  //compares with filename: you can change this to your required file!
                        if (file.getName().equals("sam2.txt")) { 

  // method to read and show the text in text view
                            loadFile(file); 



                        }

                    }
```

finally the definition of loadFile() method:

```
private void loadFile(File file) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   FileInputStream fIn;
                    try {
                        fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
                        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                        String receiveString = "";
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((receiveString = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                        }
                        show.setText(stringBuilder.toString());    
                        myReader.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: i have listed all the file name in the logcat and the path an everything else is correct except that when i call the load() i get an npe. the edit2 section works just fine, i am still facing error in loadFile section

Comment: NPE on what? what the error you are facing now? canyou post the logcat where you get NPE, and what you get in logcat when printing the file name and path/

Comment: when i print the path i get it as /data/data/mypackagename/files/fave2 3,4 ie. the rest are same just the file name changes and now i dont get an npe but there is this thing i noted using Log messages, this load() is not being called, the compiler does the if check on if(file equals "myname.txt") and then it just returns no and the funtion is not called and i get a blank textView

Comment: file.equals("mytext.txt") OR file.getName().equals("mytext.txt"), which one you tried?

Comment: and i dont actually prefer the getName thing coz i woudnt know what the file names are, the program assigns it dynamically to them so could i try somthing like load() while file!=null while file is the array u defined above

Comment: then what is the criteria to chose a single file to open? can the system choose it randomely from the list of file?

Comment: getName prints all the names of the file correctly like fav1,2 3 etc

Comment: is there a way that all the files in the internal memory are just loaded without any name check or anything? the system can just choose anyone of the list and keep showing on the textView until the file array is empty

Comment: you want to show content of each file in the text view?

Comment: if the file names are getting correctly, then how your condition falls into false?

Comment: yep, get the file contents and show on a textView n i dunno the file names are retrieved correctly but the load() is not called.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67539/discussion-on-answer-by-bachu-how-to-use-input-stream-reader-to-load-files-from).